# Numpy: subtracting two arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array,say A1, of shape (1,1), and another, say A2, of shape (1,).

When I do A1-A2, I get another array of shape (1,1).

Shouldn't the arrays be of same dimensions for subtraction/sum operation?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html: "The term broadcasting describes how numpy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints, the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes."

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html), you can see that numpy uses broadcasting (duplication of the array until it matches the dimensions of the other array) on the smaller Array to ensure that the arrays have the same size and an elementwise operation is possible.